# Why could NOT the pointer-chain be allocated continously in Fortran-90?

Tags: pointers, linked-list, fortran, allocation

I'm trying to learn the data-strcuture of a linked-list using Pointers in Fortran 90 on the platform of Win32/x86.

But when I runs the test-case that simply aims to build a list of 100 items, the program terminates with and error of 'Access violation'.

And the list is far from finished before the error occurs.

In debug run, it turns out that, at some point, the allocation of NEXT-Pointer fails.

I'm wondering why could this happen?

How could the linked-list be build successfully using pointers?

Codes are as follows:

```
TYPE Ptr  
    INTEGER           :: I
    TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: PREV,NEXT
END TYPE Ptr

TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: P
INTEGER           :: IP,Err

ALLOCATE(P)

DO IP=1,100

    P%I = IP

    IF ( .NOT.ASSOCIATED(P%NEXT) ) THEN
                ALLOCATE(P%NEXT, STAT=Err ) 
    END IF

    P%NEXT%PREV => P
    P           => P%NEXT

END DO
```

Comment: Could you please give the exact status code `Err`? Alternatively, omit the `STAT=Err` and have the error printed to the terminal.

Comment: `P           => P%NEXT` ... you loose the pointer to the start of the list!

Comment: In debug run, Err is 0  ( This is also confused ); I am confused just now, when I comment  ‘IF..THEN’ and 'END IF' the codes works, and no error occurs.....???

Comment: Always define your pointer derived tyoe components as `..., pointer :: next => null()`

Comment: Thank you all very much!  NULLIFY the newly allocated pointers solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

On UBUNTU with gfortran 7.2 your program compiled and ran just fine. There are, however two issues with your program, that may trip off your compiler:
After you allocate `p` the status of the pointers `p%next` and `p%prev` is undefined. It might be that your compiler then gets tripped on the statement `IF(.not.associated(p%next))`, as the status of `p%next` is undefined. Always nullify pointers before you use them or refer to them in any which way. Try:

```
program pointers
!
TYPE Ptr
    INTEGER           :: I   
    TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: PREV,NEXT
END TYPE Ptr
!
TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: P => NULL()     ! Make sure all pointer are nullified
TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: head => NULL() 
TYPE(Ptr),POINTER :: temp => NULL() 
INTEGER           :: IP,Err
!
NULLIFY(P)     ! This is identical to the nullify in the declaration statement
NULLIFY(head)  ! I've added it to show both styles   
NULLIFY(temp)
!
ALLOCATE(P)
NULLIFY(P%NEXT)   ! Always nullify pointers
NULLIFY(P%PREV)   ! Always nullify pointers
head => P         ! To keep a header to your list is a good idea
!
DO IP=1,100
  write(*,*) ip
  P%I = IP*IP     ! Trivial unimportant change 
!
  IF ( .NOT.ASSOCIATED(P%NEXT) ) THEN
            ALLOCATE(P%NEXT, STAT=Err ) 
     P%NEXT%I = ip+1      ! define entries
     NULLIFY(P%NEXT%NEXT) ! for next node
     NULLIFY(P%NEXT%PREV) ! for all elements of your TYPE
  END IF
! 
  P%NEXT%PREV => P
  P           => P%NEXT
!
END DO
!
temp => head                ! temporary pointer to navigate
DO WHILE( ASSOCIATED(temp) )
  write(*,*) ' AT NODE ', temp%i
  temp => temp%next
ENDDO
!
end program pointers
```

As pointed out by @Alexander Vogt, you loose the start of the list. I added a pointer called head to retain this beginning of the list. If you look at the output you will notice that the program actually makes a list of 100+1 entries, since you make `p` first, then you add 100 times a `p%next`.

Comment: I'm very grateful! It helps me learn a lot